# Python df error (pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm having an issue with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'MYAPIKEY' 

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume']]
df['HL_OCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['HL_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]

print(df.head())
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
    File "regression.py", line 11, in <module>
    df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2133, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2177, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1269, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['HL_PCT' 'PCT_change'] not in index"
```

I'm not quite sure why it's not working. I've installed Pandas, Quandl and skLearn using pip.
I'm running this on my ubuntu vm if that helps..

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

UPDATE:

Running this

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume',]]

print(df.head())
```

produces this output, so the columns are definitely there!

```
            Adj. Open  Adj. High   Adj. Low  Adj. Close  Adj. Volume
Date                                                                
2004-08-19  50.159839  52.191109  48.128568   50.322842   44659000.0
2004-08-20  50.661387  54.708881  50.405597   54.322689   22834300.0
2004-08-23  55.551482  56.915693  54.693835   54.869377   18256100.0
2004-08-24  55.792225  55.972783  51.945350   52.597363   15247300.0
2004-08-25  52.542193  54.167209  52.100830   53.164113    9188600.0
>>>
```

EDIT:

Seems like I've fixed this myself. I'm not sure how, but now when running

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]
print(df.head())
```

I get the desired output of

```
            Adj. Close    HL_PCT  PCT_change  Adj. Volume
Date                                                     
2004-08-19   50.322842  3.712563    0.324968   44659000.0
2004-08-20   54.322689  0.710922    7.227007   22834300.0
2004-08-23   54.869377  3.729433   -1.227880   18256100.0
2004-08-24   52.597363  6.417469   -5.726357   15247300.0
2004-08-25   53.164113  1.886792    1.183658    9188600.0
>>>
```

Comment: Check `df.columns`, it seems you are trying to reference columns that don't exist.

Comment: @jpp The columns are definitely there. Check the post again - I've just updated it showing the columns :)

Comment: @jpp I see where the mistake is now. I was supposed to type HL_PCT, but I accidentally typed OCT

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @MasoudPourbozorg Indeed I have

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I've fixed this myself. I'm not sure how, but now when running

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')

df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]
print(df.head())
```

I get the desired output of

```
            Adj. Close    HL_PCT  PCT_change  Adj. Volume
Date                                                     
2004-08-19   50.322842  3.712563    0.324968   44659000.0
2004-08-20   54.322689  0.710922    7.227007   22834300.0
2004-08-23   54.869377  3.729433   -1.227880   18256100.0
2004-08-24   52.597363  6.417469   -5.726357   15247300.0
2004-08-25   53.164113  1.886792    1.183658    9188600.0
>>>
```